# In C++, can you create an object as arg to function?

Tags: c++, object

In the following simple two classes

```
class B {
  private:
    int i;
  public:
    B( int p_i ) { i = p_i; };
}
class C {
  private:
    B* b;
  public:
    C( B* p_b ) { b = p_b; };
}
```

is it legal to create `B` as an argument to `C()`?

for example, is

```
C c = C( &B(5) );
```

legal, creating `B` on the fly?

Comment: You create a class in C++ with a text editor by writing some code. A C++ program cannot create a class. It creates **objects**. Please learn the distinction and use correct terminology.

Comment: In your case, you are getting the address of a temporary object that is going to be destructed immediately after. Therefore it would be risky.

Comment: I guess it's legal, but pointless (pun intended)

Comment: @n.m. - right. corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an object on the fly. Any C++ program does it all the time. Such objects are called temporaries.

You cannot take an address of a temporary though. So `&B(5)` is illegal. Your compiler will tell you that if you try to compile this code.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing compiles, but it's wrong! that object will be created and destroyed immediately, unless you copy it in the constructor, which is a waste.

A typical way to do this ([in Qt, for instance](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Use_QTableWidget), see the section "Insert Data"), is to use pointers (I'm not encouraging this, read below):

```
C c = C( new B(5) );
```

This is safe, but is dangerous, because you will have to free that memory yourself. Therefore, you should consider using [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

The reason this is OK in Qt, is because Qt manages memory in a different way. `C` would be a *parent* of the `B` object, and will delete it when itself gets destroyed.

Comment: It is not dangerous, but normal practice to create objects on the heap using `new` and to destroy them using `delete `. It happens in code all the time. You learn how to use them properly in every c++ course.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius It's the worst practice ever. Don't ever say what you said here in a job interview, that's my advice to you. Again: Learn about smart pointers.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius Btw, I noticed you're an embedded engineer. Notice that we're talking about C++, not C. In embedded systems everything is different. If you have C++ and you have the concept of "destructors" working fine, then you shouldn't manually delete objects.

Comment: Smart pointers weren't introduced until C++11, unless you used boost. If you don't know new and delete, you will never be able to maintain legacy code. Edit: lol, you think embedded systems are only programmed in c? That was way long ago.... I have been programming c++ for 12 years now. (And c, Matlab, Python, c#, vhdl...)

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius Smart pointers is a very old concept, again, you could just use a destructor. (check the 2005 book called "Professional C++"). The concept of smart pointers was in C++ since a long time, but it was implementation dependent. Then there was `auto_ptr` which has some problems with moving objects. But now C++11 has the ultimate solution with unique and shared pointers.

Comment: So next time I maintain old code, you suggest me to find-and-replace-all new for shared_ptr... I bet that will work splendid. ;p

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius Dude... what are you doing? We're talking about *good style*. You can code as bad you want! There's good practice and there's bad practice, and hence there are tons of books just on coding good style! Maintaining old code is a different issue. I just hope you're joking here! Old is OLD! It's legacy! It's something that you use to save money and not rework stuff. You know what can save money too? Good style! Seriously, consider googling this topic and reading about it a little.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136136/discussion-between-j-h-bonarius-and-the-quantum-physicist).

Answer (score 2):

Even if you can it will cause an Undefined Behavior. Program may or may not work depending on unpredictable conditions.